# FTP Send command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp, ftplib

I have a batch file that runs every night in which it ftps a file over.  In that batch I have this line echo send C:\send*.txt>> ftpcmd.dat.  This works perfectly when there is only one file in the send folder and I only want to send one file the newest one, but when there are numerous files sometimes it sends the newest one sometimes it doesn't.  Im not sure what determines what file is sent when I use a '*' as the filename.

```
@echo off
echo user > ftpcmd.dat
echo psswd> ftpcmd.dat
echo ascii>> ftpcmd.dat
echo send C:\newgdrive\boldata\send\*.txt>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.thinktbl.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Comment: If you answer my question you'll be my first acceptance

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to make your pwd public... I strongly suggest changing it before somebody abuses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `send` command correctly transmits a single file to the server.

In order to transmit multiple files, you may use `mput` instead of `send`.

Also, commands acting on multiple files such as `mput` cause prompting (y/n) - you may want to disable this by calling `prompt` before using `mput`.

Your ftpcmd.dat should look like this:

```
user vigftp
mypwd
ascii
prompt
mput C:\newgdrive\boldata\send\*.txt
quit
```